How to split a .xlsx file into multiple .csvs using python in snowflake?
I have a .xlsx file stored within a blob storage container thats been integrated into a snowflake stage environment, so I can access it in Snowflake. I am trying to have python (run within a snowflake stored procedure) split the .xlsx file into multiple .csv files within the same stage environment.
I have been using a combination of this post and co-pilot to get some form of working stored procedure, but its not working and returning an error. The error that reoccurs is:
Python Interpreter Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python_udf/07da35646d4f3b655d96bf0222d31c191a6797e450b0ac0eef955ee969f584c8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/base.py", line 59, in _convert
    value = expected_type(value)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.date)
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_udf_code.py", line 10, in main
    workbook = load_workbook(f, data_only=True, read_only=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python_udf/07da35646d4f3b655d96bf0222d31c191a6797e450b0ac0eef955ee969f584c8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 348, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python_udf/07da35646d4f3b655d96bf0222d31c191a6797e450b0ac0eef955ee969f584c8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 295, in read
    self.read_properties()
  File "/usr/lib/python_udf/07da35646d4f3b655d96bf0222d31c191a6797e450b0ac0eef955ee969f584c8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 176, in read_properties
    self.wb.properties = DocumentProperties.from_tree(src)
  File "/usr/lib/python_udf/07da35646d4f3b655d96bf0222d31c191a6797e450b0ac0eef955ee969f584c8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/serialisable.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
  File "/usr/lib/python_udf/07da35646d4f3b655d96bf0222d31c191a6797e450b0ac0eef955ee969f584c8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/packaging/core.py", line 107, in __init__
    self.modified = modified or now
  File "/usr/lib/python_udf/07da35646d4f3b655d96bf0222d31c191a6797e450b0ac0eef955ee969f584c8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/base.py", line 272, in __set__
    super().__set__(instance, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python_udf/07da35646d4f3b655d96bf0222d31c191a6797e450b0ac0eef955ee969f584c8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/nested.py", line 33, in __set__
    super().__set__(instance, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python_udf/07da35646d4f3b655d96bf0222d31c191a6797e450b0ac0eef955ee969f584c8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/base.py", line 71, in __set__
    value = _convert(self.expected_type, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python_udf/07da35646d4f3b655d96bf0222d31c191a6797e450b0ac0eef955ee969f584c8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/base.py", line 61, in _convert
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))
TypeError: expected <class 'datetime.datetime'>
 in function SPLIT_XLSX_TO_CSV_PROC with handler main

It references requiring an interget but got a datetime.date, however I have asked it to store all data within the .xlsx as strings.
My (frankly terrible) code is below. I am still learning python so please excuse any rookie mistakes or clearly co-pilot inspired mistakes.
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE split_xlsx_to_csv_proc(file_path string, sheet_to_process string, sheet_to_ignore string, target_stage string)

RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.8'
PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python', 'pandas', 'openpyxl')
HANDLER = 'main'
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import os, sys, csv
import pandas as pd

def main(session, file_path, sheet_to_process, sheet_to_ignore, target_stage):
session.file.get(file_path, "/tmp/")
file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
with open(os.path.join("/tmp", file_name), "rb") as f: 
    workbook = load_workbook(f, data_only=True, read_only=True)
    
    # Check if the sheet to process is the one to ignore
    if sheet_to_process == sheet_to_ignore:
        return f"Sheet '{sheet_to_ignore}' is set to be ignored."
    
    # Choose the desired worksheet
    worksheet = workbook[sheet_to_process]
    
    # Open the CSV file in write mode
    with open("/tmp/exported.csv", 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        # Iterate through rows in the worksheet and write to the CSV file
        for row in worksheet.iter_rows(values_only=True):
            csv_writer.writerow([str(cell) if cell is not None else '' for cell in row])
    
    # Close the workbook
    workbook.close()
    session.file.put("file:///tmp/exported.csv", target_stage)

return os.path.join(target_stage, "exported.csv")
$$;

I have tried to have it set up so you define one sheet you want it to copy, and one sheet to ignore (as theres one sheet that I thought contained bad data, but even if you ignore that sheet it still returns errors)
Is anyone able to help me troubleshoot this? I hoped it would be a simple task and maybe I am over complicating it, but nothing seems to work?

I'm not an expert in this area, but this issue is likely related to your python code trying to leverage local paths on the warehouse.  I doubt that is possible from within Snowflake's environment.  I would recommend trying to load the XLSX into a dataframe first and then exporting the dataframe to a stage.  Or if you are more comfortable, load a pandas dataframe into a Snowflake table and then run a COPY INTO from that table to a stage.

This is much easier using pandas which you are already using:
with open(r"c:\temp\orders.xlsx","rb") as xl:
   df = pd.read_excel(xl,SheetName)

with open(r"c:\temp\orders.csv","w") as csv:
    df.to_csv(csv, index=False)

